# c++ calculate the sum of two array's and output a boolean '0' if result even else '1' if odd

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, function-definition

[image]

I was hoping to find an **alternative solution/method** to mine for solving the above question given the set parameters. Essentially the way I went about it was to loop through the two arrays simultaneous and add the corresponding values. First place would have been to use a conditional operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

//an array of size 0 [no elements]
void myLists(int list1[], int list2[], int list3[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ((list1[i] + list2[i]) % 2 == 0) // return the modulo of the two array sums
        {
            cout << (list3[i] == true);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << (list3[i] == false);
        };
    }
}
int main()
{
    //initialize the two arrays
    int list1[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int list2[5]{0, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    int list3[5]{};
    int size{};

    size = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);

    myLists(list1, list2, list3, size);

    return 0;
}
```

RESULTS OF CODE:

> 10101

Comment: You don't fill `list3[]`. Why do you compare an unitialized value with false/true?

Comment: I think your code seems to work by coincidence, but is actually wrong.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the coincidence is in the `ìf` condition. It alternates.

Comment: @Ripi2 yes I know, the two mistakes cancel each other out.

Comment: Regardless, `list3` is never modified in this program, despite requirements that it be populated.  Every `list3[i]` could be replaced with `0`.  Possibly `list3[i] == ` was intended to be `list3[i] = `.

Comment: This algorithm exists: in the standard library [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: @mkrieger1 hoping to find an alternative solution, the idea is to learn, I don't mind being roasted.

Comment: @GDube your professor is trying to give you a hint with the output I'd suggest reading up on [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: @Ripi2 How else would I get the boolean value? How would you have went about it might I ask?

Comment: Just at the beguinnig of the `for` loop: `list3[i]= (list1[i] + list2[i]) % 2;` Then, the `if` condition becomes `if(list[3] == 1)`

Comment: @Ripi2 Thank you, your method makes sense and it works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
void myLists( const int list1[], const int list2[], int list3[], size_t size ;
```

because neither the first parameter nor the second parameter are being changed within the function.

The function does not set elements of the third array. As the third array is zero initialized

```
int list3[5]{};
```

then this expression `list3[i] == true` always evaluates to `false`  and this expression `list3[i] == false` always evaluates to `true`.

In fact you could write

```
if ((list1[i] + list2[i]) % 2 == 0) // return the modulo of the two array sums
{
    list3[i] = list3[i] == true;
}
else
{
    list3[i] = list3[i] == false;
};
```

or

```
list3[i] = (list1[i] + list2[i]) % 2 == 0 ? list3[i] == true : list3[i] == false;
```

But this looks clumsy and moreover **in general this approach is incorrect and can result in undefined behavior** because the user can pass an uninitialized array as the third argument.

It would be much better and correct to write

```
list3[i] = ( list1[i] + list2[i] ) % 2;
```

An alternative approach is to use the standard algorithm `std::transform`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void myLists( const int list1[], const int list2[], int list3[], size_t size )
{
    std::transform( list1, list1 + size, list2, list3,
                    [] ( const auto &a, const auto &b )
                    {
                        return a % 2 ^ b % 2;
                    });
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t size = 5; 
    int list1[size] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int list2[size] = { 0, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    int list3[size];
    
    myLists( list1, list2, list3, size );
    
    for ( const auto &item : list3 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 0 1 0 1
```

In the return statement of the lambda expression there is used the logical XOR operator instead of the expression `( a + b ) % 2` to avoid integer overflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

void myList(int list1[], int list2[], int list3[], int size) {
    std::transform(
            list1, list1 + size,
            list2,
            list3,
            [](int elem1, int elem2) { return (elem1 + elem2) % 2; }
        );
}
int main() {
    int list1[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int list2[5]{0, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    int list3[5]{};
    int size = sizeof(list1) / sizeof(list1[0]);

    myList(list1, list2, list3, size);
    for (auto elem : list3) {
        std::cout << elem;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Or if you want a raw loop:

```
void myList(int list1[], int list2[], int list3[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list3[i] = (list1[i] + list2[i]) % 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not familiar with the method of using transform, @chris mentioned it, Thank you for this, I will practise it going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to actually add two integer to see if their sum is even or odd.

You know that numbers with the same "oddness" will add to even number, and with different - to odd.

An alternative to `%2` is a bitwise `&` for the last bit; if `n & 1` is true, `n` is odd.

So if `n & 1` is the same as `m & 1` - `n + m` is even. You can check for that with the `XOR` operator `^`:

```
list3[i] = (list1[i] & 1) ^ (list2[i] & 1);
```